# Fire off angular $exceptionHandler from chrome repl

Tags: angularjs, exceptionhandler

I am overriding the default `$exceptionHandler`, similar to what is seen here on angular's site: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$exceptionHandler

works great.

However, I am semi-unclear as to how to 'watch' this process when not `$emit`'ing a named event whom's handler explicitly passes the error (conjured or otherwise) down into the $exceptionHandler (which is injected in the `.directive || .config || .service | .run || etc... ).

TL:DR - I would like to know how to simulate an unhandled exception which the default angular $exceptionHandler is meant to pick up - specifically from the chrome console/REPL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the code that generates the exception inside the digest loop. More specifically you need to pass it to `$apply`, since `$digest` itself does not use `$exceptionHandler`.

Pseudocode for `$apply`:

```
function $apply(expr) {
  try {
    return $eval(expr);
  } catch (e) {
    $exceptionHandler(e);
  } finally {
    $root.$digest();
  }
}
```

So from the console you can for example do this:

```
window.test = function(fn) {
  angular.element(document.querySelector('.ng-scope'))
  .injector()
  .get('$rootScope')
  .$apply(fn);
}

window.test(function () { var a = b; });

window.test(function () { throw "Error"; });
```